# Creating an array based on user input MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, multidimensional-array, mips

I am trying to figure out how to create a 2D array, then search the array based on user input.

It would prompt the user for (rows, columns): (2, 7)

it would then return the random number from that index.

This is what I have so far, it will create a 10x10 array filled with random numbers. I can't seem to figure out how to prompt the user with the row, column number, and return the number in that index. If the user puts a 0 from row or column, the program will exit.

```
.data
list:   .space 400
stew: .word 100

    .text

main:
    lw $s0, stew
    la $s1, list
    li $a0, 1
    jal array
    li $t0, 0


array:
    beq $t0, $s0, return

    li $v0, 42
    li $a1, 9
    syscall

    sw $a0, ($s1)
    addi $t0, $t0,  1
    addi $s1, $s1, 4
    j array

return:
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Which part is causing you problems? What have you tried? See also [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @Jester I added what I had to the question above, I reserved a space for a 10x10 array and saved random number is spaces. I can't seem to figure out how to get the row,column from user and search within that index for the number.

Comment: I assume you know how to get a number from the user (syscall #5). Then just fetch the item at index `10*row+column` which I hope you can also calculate. If you still have some problem, be more specific.

Comment: @Jester Wouldn't I have to multiply the row entry by 10 and the column entry by 4? Since each row consists of 10 numbers there are 40 pieces of memory per row, then the column by 4 to get the number in that specific column?   My next question would be, what if the user entered (1,1)? It wouldn't give them the value in index 1, because of the multiplicaiton.

Comment: Yes,  you need to scale both for bytes, I just told you which item to get. You also need to offset by 1 if you expect the user to enter 1-based indices.

Comment: @Jester I have figured all of it out. Thanks so much for the help.                         How would I input an integer into a random spot within the array? For example, if a user input is 9, it would randomly place it within an empty array.

Comment: Use the random syscall #42.